# How to perfom a "findAll" on a Projection with spring and Mongodb?

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I have a Document in a MongoDB. My document is as follow :

```
[{
 name: "toto",
 age: "30",
 address:{
   city: "Paris",
   street: "Rue de la paix"
 }
}]
```

Now, I have some models Java class :

```
class Address{
 public String city;
 public String street;
}
class Person{
 public String id;
 public String name;
 public int age;
 public Address address;
}
```

I would like to perform a projection to retrieve only names and city of my "Persons"... So I create an interface like this :

```
interface OnlyCity{
public String getCity();
}
interface NameAndCity{
 public String getName();
 public OnlyCity getAddress();
}
```

And in my repository I would like to create a Method to retrieve all the "NameAndCity"...

Now, I would like to perfom a "findAll" on this projection. In other words, to get all names and city of persons in my database.

The only way I found to do it is as follow :

```
public interface PersonsRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, String>{

    List<NameAndCity> findNameAndCityByNameRegex(String regex);
}
```

And calling this method with the following regex : ".*"... That works.

**But is it possible to override "findAll()" to return the projected value ?**

Comment: I went through the documentation for spring projection and It's not possible through projection but there is a way we can do that. We can create a model for each OnlyCity  & NameAndCity instead of projection interface and create a repository NameAndCityRepository and use the findAll to populate the models which uses the persistence context. Very much similar to the findAll for person repository.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
public interface PersonsRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, String>{

    List<NameAndCity> findByIdIsNotNull();
}
```